Where does dnf history comment appear?
DNF can apply comments to history entries, by --comment=value option.
Is there a command to display that comment? Having added a comment, I tried to list history and to get history entry info by ID but saw no comment.

I didn't find a way to show the comment in dnf history list output but it is shown by default in the detailed description of the transaction you can get using dnf history info <transaction ID>:
$ sudo dnf history info 1125
Transaction ID : 1125
Begin time     : Tue 30 Jul 2024 02:59:03 PM CEST
Begin rpmdb    : db8710dafe41ef3c11fc59360d9861a59b6bcbf4f0340ddce7065a3c288865b9
End time       : Tue 30 Jul 2024 02:59:05 PM CEST (2 seconds)
End rpmdb      : 229c4a75e141fd7427f22a1ef434299aa70a48c1b1c839d4a54bda9527cab80e
User           : Vojtěch Trefný <vtrefny>
Return-Code    : Success
Releasever     : 39
Command Line   : update --comment=Comment
Comment        : Comment

If you want to show comments for all transactions in history it would be probably easiest to use the DNF Python API and create your own version of history list with something like:
import dnf
base = dnf.Base()
for trans in base.history.old(): 
    print(trans.tid, trans.cmdline, trans.comment)

which will print
1125 update --comment=Comment Comment
...


Could you output your DNF version please? Mine does not include comment field.

4.21.0 (Fedora 39)
